# docker volume nfs permission denied

Tags: ubuntu, docker, freebsd, volume, nfs

I'm hitting a wall :(

I try to use a NFS volume in docker for sharing / accessing container state data over a docker swarm. But I allready fail in creating a working volume. 
I read a lot of SO threads, the docker documentation, etc.

As far as I can tell there are at least two ways to get this done. The built in `docker volume` and external docker-volume driver. I would prefer to use the `docker volume`

I use a FreeBSD machine as NFS Server and two ubuntu clients as docker nodes. I created the NFS share and mounted it manually on the ubuntu machines:

```
mount -o v3 -t nfs 10.0.0.108:/usr/srv/docker/registry /mnt
mount | grep nfs
    10.0.0.108:/usr/srv/docker on /mnt type nfs (rw,relatime,vers=3,rsize=131072,wsize=131072,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=10.0.0.108,mountvers=3,mountport=794,mountproto=udp,local_lock=none,addr=10.0.0.108)
```

So far so good. Now I try to create a docker volume:

```
docker volume create \
    --driver local \
    --opt type=nfs \
    --opt device=:/usr/srv/docker/registry \
    --opt "o=addr=10.0.0.108,vers=3,rw" 
    registry
```

Here I tried several versions of `"o=...."`.

Docker returns a success in creating the volume... or it simply writes the volume name, without any comment :)

Next step: Testing the volume:

```
docker run --rm -i -v=registry:/tmp/myvolume busybox ls -lA /tmp/myvolume
```

That's the moment where the errors "pile up".

On the NFS Server:

```
Mar 27 17:17:51 $host mountd[1002]: mount request denied from 10.0.0.106 for /usr/srv/docker/registry
```

On the docker node:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: 
 error while mounting volume '/var/lib/docker/volumes/registry/_data': 
  error while mounting volume with options: 
   type='nfs' device=':/usr/srv/docker/registry' o='addr=10.0.0.108,vers=3,mountaddr=10.0.0.108,mountvers=3': 
    permission denied.
```

As far as I understand the documentation the `permission denied` is an output of the kernel/nfs-client. But I don't understand why this happens.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

EDIT:
Used Docker version is:

```
Docker version 17.12.1-ce, build 7390fc6
```

Comment: Which version of docker do you use??

Comment: i added the version, thanks for asking @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd

Comment: Port 111 (TCP and UDP) and 2049 (TCP and UDP) need to be open for the NFS server. Check out the firewall rules on your machines.

Answer (score 0):

On the FreeBSD server you muss allow the filesystem to be mounted.

check your mountpoint with:

```
mount
```

Then edit or create the /etc/exports file:

```
# if /usr/srv/docker/registry is a moutpoint 
/usr/srv/docker/registry -network 10.0.0.0 -mask 255.0.0.0
# if /usr/srv/docker/registry is a direcoty under /usr
/usr -alldirs -network 10.0.0.0 -mask 255.0.0.0
```

If you use ZFS you can also activate the sharing with "zfs", see manpage.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but mounting is possible, only the docker cli can't do it. The ubuntu server itself is able to mount the nfs share. I shared the share with `zfs sharenfs ...`

Comment: Did you tried from the IP of your docker container?

Comment: Good idea! Just checked it out. The container uses the external node IP when communicating with the nfs-server. So 10.0.0.106, just as the node when mounting directly. Mounting inside a running container doesn't seem to be possible (permission denied, but on every mount i try, not just nfs)